# Get link to archive post type POST

Tags: wordpress, post, archive

I use

`get_post_type_archive_link`

but it's work, only custom post type , but i want get link to the archive post type POST

Comment: Does get_post_type_archive_link( 'post' ); work?

Comment: it's doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
```

With fallback:

```
function posts_archive_link() {
    if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
        if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) {
            echo get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
        } else {
            echo home_url( '/?post_type=post' );
        }
    } else {
        echo home_url( '/' );
    }
}
```